# How to find out where the method was called in Java?

Tags: java, debugging

I have more than 100 class files. I got an error message in one method when it return values. Example:

```
public String name()
{
    return("John");  // error message appeared here
}
```

My problem is that I couldn't find out where this has been called.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: check your stacktrace it has all you need

Answer (score 1):

You may print the calling stack this way :

```
for (StackTraceElement ste : Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()) {
    System.out.println(ste);
}
```

Note that most IDE have shortcuts to find where a given method is called.

*For instance in Eclipse, you would select your method, then  Ctrl+Shift+G will show you all possible callers of the method.*

You may also use a debugger and do step-by-step check.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
StackTraceElement[] ste = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()
```

From [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadInfo.html#getStackTrace()):

> Returns the stack trace of the thread associated with this ThreadInfo.
>   If no stack trace was requested for this thread info, this method will
>   return a zero-length array. If the returned array is of non-zero
>   length then the first element of the array represents the top of the
>   stack, which is the most recent method invocation in the sequence. The
>   last element of the array represents the bottom of the stack, which is
>   the least recent method invocation in the sequence.